# Java: how to let compiler show error when specific classes defined constructors which has any argument?

Tags: java, constructor, annotations, preprocessor

Sometimes, some classes will be only dynamically instantiated by Class.newInstance(), such classes should not define any constructor which has any argument because they will not be called anywhere.

e.g.,

- Example1 (good):

```
public class DynamicClass1 {
  // no any constructor defined, this is good for dynamic instantiation, there will be a implicit no-arg constructor created.
}
```

- Example2 (good):

```
public class DynamicClass1 {
   public DynamicClass() { ... }
}
```

- example3 (**BAD**):

```
public class DynamicClass1 {
  public DynamicClass1(String xxx) { ... }
}
```

probably the author expect the constructor being called, but actually it is not called from anywhere and will not, so I want the compiler show an error message "the constructor you defined will never be called".

Is there any idea?
Maybe I need create my own annotation processor?

Answer (score 2):

Your description matches the concept of [service providers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html#designing-services-heading). When you use service providers together with Java modules, you get the compile-time check automatically.

E.g., a minimal setup for a module would look like:

###### modulespackage/StaticAPI.java

```java
package modulespackage;

public abstract class StaticAPI
{
}
```

###### modulespackage/DynamicClass1.java

```java
package modulespackage;

public class DynamicClass1 extends StaticAPI
{
  // public DynamicClass1() {}
}
```

###### module-info.java

```java
import modulespackage.*;

module example {
  provides StaticAPI with DynamicClass1;
  uses StaticAPI;
}
```

The `provides StaticAPI with DynamicClass1;` is the declaration mandating that `DynamicClass1` must be a subclass of `StaticAPI` and have a `public` no-arg constructor. Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

The `uses StaticAPI;` allows the module to write something like

```java
StaticAPI api = ServiceLoader.load(StaticAPI.class).findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("missing service"));
```

to get hands on a service provider implementation of `StaticAPI` which will be an instance of `DynamicClass1` if that’s the only provider. The [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) API allows you to iterate over all implementations if there is more than one and/or select a particular implementation based on your own rules.

Note that this mechanism allows an alternative implementation, a `public` `static` method `provider()` returning the actual implementation instead of using a no-arg constructor, but you don’t have to worry about it if you’re using [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) to acquire the instance, as it will do the right thing for you.

The `provides` and `uses` declarations don’t have to be in the same module, even the abstract base class or interface may be in yet another module, but the package containing the API declaration must be exported to the module(s) implementing and/or using the API.

---

Unfortunately, the non-modular version of the service provider mechanism is as dynamic as in your problem description, not providing you compile-time checks whether the implementation classes are sufficient.